# Simple PyQt5 Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pyqt

I have started learning PyQt5 and wanted to create a simple window to test my skills.
So I have created this window and I want to receive reviews on any aspect of the code.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout,QSplitter, QFormLayout, QLabel, QFrame, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_menu_bar()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.create_body()
        self.show()


    def create_menu_bar(self):
        title = 'First Porgram'
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(300, 150, 500, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color:#333;color:#ccc')
        self.setFont(QFont('Serif', 10))
        self.menu_bar = self.menuBar()

        self.file_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("File")
        self.file_menu.addAction('New')
        self.file_menu.addAction('Open')
        self.file_menu.addAction('Save')
        self.file_menu.addAction('Save as')
        self.file_menu.addAction('Exit') 

        self.view_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("View")
        self.view_menu.addAction('set Full Screen')
        self.view_menu.addAction('show Status Bar') 

        self.edit_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("Edit")
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Cut')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Copy')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Paste')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Find')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Replace') 

        self.help_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("Help")
        self.help_menu.addAction('Help')
        self.help_menu.addAction('About')


    def create_body(self):

        form_frame = QFrame()
        form_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        form_frame.setMinimumWidth(150)
        form_lay = QFormLayout()
        f_label = QLabel('Welcome')
        s_label = QLabel('Installation')
        p_push = QPushButton('Sign in')
        p_push.setContentsMargins(10, 20, 10, 10)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        form_lay.addRow(f_label)
        form_lay.addRow(s_label)
        form_lay.addRow(p_push)
        form_frame.setLayout(form_lay)

        ver_frame = QFrame()
        ver_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        ver_box = QVBoxLayout()
        ver_box.setContentsMargins(25, 20, 25, 25)
        intro_label = QLabel("Welcome to The  Open Space ")
        intro_label.setFont(QFont('Serif', 16))
        ver_box.addWidget(intro_label)
        ver_frame.setLayout(ver_box)

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter.addWidget(form_frame)
        splitter.addWidget(ver_frame)

        self.vbox.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setCentralWidget(splitter)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        men = QMenu()
        men.addAction('New')
        men.addAction('Open')
        quit = men.addAction('Quit')
        action = men.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        if action is quit:
           self.close()

def main():
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     win = Window()
     app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

here is a screenshot of my window
[image]

Also, how can I add to a top margin on my sign in button, and is there any way I can inherit my context menu's color from my class?

Answer (score 1):

**Qt Style Sheets** Reference https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

> Qt Style Sheets support various properties, pseudo-states, 
>   .and subcontrols that make it possible to customize the look of widgets.

**Qt Style Sheets Examples** https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QSplitter, 
                             QFormLayout, QLabel, QFrame, QPushButton, 
                             QMenu, QAction)                                      # + 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui  import QFont, QIcon


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.create_menu_bar()
#        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()                                                # -
        self.create_body()

    def create_menu_bar(self):
        self.menu_bar = self.menuBar()

        self.file_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("File")
        self.file_menu.addAction('New')
        self.file_menu.addAction('Open')
        self.file_menu.addAction('Save')
        self.file_menu.addAction('Save as')

#        self.file_menu.addAction('Exit') 
        # +++
        self.exit_menu = QAction(QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/exit.png"),'&Exit', self)
        self.exit_menu.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exit_menu.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.exit_menu)         

        self.view_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("View")
        self.view_menu.addAction('set Full Screen')
        self.view_menu.addAction('show Status Bar') 

        self.edit_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("Edit")
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Cut')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Copy')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Paste')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Find')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Replace') 

        self.help_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("Help")
        self.help_menu.addAction('Help')
        self.help_menu.addAction('About')

    def create_body(self):
        form_frame = QFrame()
        form_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        form_frame.setMinimumWidth(150)

        f_label = QLabel('Welcome')
        s_label = QLabel('Installation')
        p_push = QPushButton('Sign in')
        p_push.setContentsMargins(10, 20, 10, 10)

        form_lay = QFormLayout()
        form_lay.addRow(f_label)
        form_lay.addRow(s_label)
        form_lay.addRow(p_push)
        form_frame.setLayout(form_lay)

        ver_frame = QFrame()
        ver_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        intro_label = QLabel("Welcome to The  Open Space ")
        intro_label.setFont(QFont('Serif', 16))

        ver_box = QVBoxLayout()
        ver_box.setContentsMargins(25, 20, 25, 25)        
        ver_box.addWidget(intro_label)
        ver_frame.setLayout(ver_box)

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter.addWidget(form_frame)
        splitter.addWidget(ver_frame)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setCentralWidget(splitter)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        men = QMenu()
        men.addAction('New')
        men.addAction('Open')
        quit = men.addAction('Quit')
        action = men.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        if action is quit:
           self.close()


StyleSheet = '''
QMainWindow {
    background-color: #333;
    color: red;
}

/* QMenuBar --------------------------------------------------------------- */

QMenuBar {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1,
                                      stop:0 lightgray, stop:1 darkgray);
}
QMenuBar::item {
    spacing: 3px;           
    padding: 2px 10px;
    background-color: rgb(210,105,30);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);  
    border-radius: 5px;
}
QMenuBar::item:selected {    
    background-color: rgb(244,164,96);
}
QMenuBar::item:pressed {
    background: rgb(128,0,0);
}

/* QMenu ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

QMenu {
    font: 12pt;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
QMenu::item:selected {
    color: gray;
}

/* QSplitter -------------------------------------------------------------- */

QSplitter::handle:horizontal {
    width: 2px;
    background-color : green;
}

QSplitter::handle:vertical {
    height: 2px;
    background-color : green;
}

/*  ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

QLabel {
/*    background-color : blue;*/
    color: #ccc;
}

QPushButton {
    min-width: 36px;
    min-height: 36px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: #777;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    color: white;
    background: #999;
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #bbdefb;
    color: green;
}

'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                                    # <---

    win = Window()
    win.setWindowTitle('First Porgram')
    win.setWindowIcon(QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png")) 
    win.setGeometry(300, 150, 500, 300)
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Good answers that get upvoted contain observations about the Original Posters code. Good answers may not contain any code at all. Could you please comment on the users code as well. Please take a look at our guidelines for a good answer at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer.